# Prisma Client not initalised while deployin app to AWS Lambda through Arc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, automatic-ref-counting, prisma, remix

I'm trying to deploy a remix.js app to Lambda through arc. While running app using **npx run dev**, everything functions properly. But when I use **npx arc sandbox** or deploy and run through aws lambda, I'm getting a **Lambda init error**

: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again. In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues

````
Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.,In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues,    at new PrismaClient (D:\appfolder\server\node_modules\.prisma\client\index.js:5:11),    at Object. (D:\appfolder\app\db.server.ts:17:21),    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14),    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10),    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32),    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12),    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19),    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18),    at run ([eval]:1:2236),    at main ([eval]:1:6973)```

I have tried generating prisma client multiple times and its working properly. The app runs without arc with no issues.
````